# CSV formatting in web request

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, csv, asp.net-web-api

I am using a javascript charting control (d3 scatter chart) that requires CSV input. 
The control has two available methods of requesting the CSV data - Point at a CSV file, or a URL that will return CSV data. The method I need to use is latter. When watching the respsonses through IE developer tools I can see that when loading the data from a CSV file I get the following response:

[image]

and when I try and create the CSV string server side (ASP.Net Web API), the following is returned:

[image]

I have two issues here:

1) The response is enclosed within quotation marks

2) The string shows /r/n instead of an actual carriage return

below is the server side code to generate a test CSV string.

[image]

How can I generate properly formatted CSV data from my server side method?

Answer (score 0):

The response is in json format as the JsonMediaTypeFormatter is writing this response. Instead you could return a HttpResponseMessage having StringContent, which does not pass through the formatters.

A more elegant solution might be is to implement a CSV media type formatter for these scenarios. 
Example here:
http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/creating-custom-csvmediatypeformatter-in-asp-net-web-api-for-comma-separated-values-csv-format